# Magento 2: Capturing Coupon Code Application / Cancelling

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.0

I cannot find a useful event for capturing when a coupon has been applied / cancelled and then updating the my cached version of the cart details.

The events I've tried:

```
// seems to only update when you add/remove a product
checkout_cart_save_after

// seems to only be useful when trying to discard a coupon before it is processed
salesrule_validator_process

// again, only seems to be for actual cart items, not coupons
checkout_cart_update_items_after
```

Any pointers would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

For Capturing event you can use at time of application of coupon,

**controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponpost**

and another used is,

**controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponpost**

You can manage as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks the **controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponpost** solved my problem. It happens _after_ the coupon has been applied so cart / quote details have been updated.